# Rails AJAX form submission

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to submit a form via AJAX. When I submit the form, it should send an ajax and fade in to the div with id stepTwo, and fadeout the current div. I am using jQuery 1.8.0, and I have this error in my console when I submit.

```
 NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)      [nsIDOMWindow.getComputedStyle]
[Break On This Error]   

...=[]),o&&(e=" "+e);while(e){k=!1;if(j=B.exec(e))e=e.slice(j[0].length),k=d.push({...
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="stepOne">
<%= form_for @program do |f| %>
    <div>
    <label for="exerciseName">Title For Your Program</label>
    <%= f.text_field :title, :name => "exerciseName", :required => "required", :maxlength => "40" %>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label for="exerciseName">Detailed Info For Your Program</label>
    <%= f.text_area :details %>
    </div>

<%= f.submit "Next Step", :class => "exbuttons button-small red rounded3", :id =>"stepOneButton" %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

And here is my controller

# POST /programs
  # POST /programs.json
  def create
    @program = Program.new(params[:progeram])
    @program.user_id = current_user.id

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @program.save
    if request.xhr?
      render @program
    else
      redirect_to @program
    end
  else
    if request.xhr?
      render @program
    else
      flash[:error] = "Program could not be added"
      redirect_to new
    end
  end
end
end
```

And this is my Javascript file

```
function stepOne(){
    $('#new_program').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var f = $(this);
        f.find('input[type="submit"]').attr("disabled", true);
        $.ajax({
            type: f.attr("method"),
            url: f.attr("action"),
            data: f.serialize(),
            complete: function(){
                f.find('input[type="submit"]').attr("disabled", false);
            },

            success : function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $(this).fadeOut();
                $('#stepTwo').delay(400).fadeIn();
            },

            error : function(xhr, status){
                console.log(status);
            }
        });


    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the NS_ERROR_FAILURE seems to indicate that the URL is wrong or the rails controller is hitting an error.

Check that the URL the script is calling is actually correct and perhaps run it without ajax to see the error page returned by rails if the url is correct.

You also do not seem to be using the respond_to so probably do not need to include it.